# How can I remove the first apperance of a number in a list? Haskell

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

I need to make a function that takes a list and an element and returns a list in which the first occurrence of the element is removed: something like

```
removeFst [1,5,2,3,5,3,4,5,6] 5
[1,2,3,5,3,4,5,6]
```

What I tried is:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    putStr ( show $ removeFst [1,5,2,3,5,3,4,5,6] 5)

removeFst :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
removeFst [] m = []
removeFst [x] m
    | x == m     = []
    | otherwise  = [x]
removeFst (x:xs) m 
    | x == m     = xs
    | otherwise  = removeFst xs m
```

But this doesn't work... it returns the list without the first elements. I think I should make the recursive call to make the list something like:

```
removeFst (x:xs) m
    | x == m     = xs
    | otherwise  = removeFst (-- return the whole list till element x) m
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are very close, what you miss is prepending the elements before the first found `m` to the result list,

```
removeFst :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
removeFst [] m = []
removeFst (x:xs) m 
    | x == m     = xs
    | otherwise  = x : removeFst xs m
    --            ^^^ keep x /= m
```

Note that the special case for one-element lists is superfluous.

Also note that `removeFst = flip delete` with `delete` from `Data.List`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be mentioned that your function is equivalent to `Data.List.delete`.

Here another version:

```
import Data.List

removeFst xs x = front ++ drop 1 back where 
  (front, back) = break (==x) xs
```